# How to override a method for a MovieClip Symbol in Flash CS3

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I'm using flash to draw objects, then I export them and use them from flex, and I'm a beginner in flash.

I'm trying to do the override a method from the MovieClip I created. The method I'm trying to override is stop() method. I didn't write a single line of code, my movie clip is created using entirely the flash interface. I figured out how to add actions to the movie clip when a frame is reached but I'm stucked now when I'm trying to override a MovieClip method.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I suspect overriding the stop() method is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To override stop, you can do this...

```
override public function stop() : void {
 // your code here
}
```

But it doesn't sound like you need to do that. Sounds like you just need to call the method something else.